# $f_{0}, f_{1} \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $ \delta=f_{0}+\frac{d f_1}{d x} $

Tags: analysis, distribution-theory

> Let $\delta$ be the Dirac distribution on $\mathbb{R}$. Find functions $f_{0}, f_{1} \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ such that
> $$
> \delta=f_{0}+\frac{d f_1}{d x}
> $$

Note: The derivative given above is in the distributional sense. For every test function $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}) = C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. The above relation will satisfy $$\delta(\phi) = \phi(0) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_0(x)\phi(x)dx+\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_1(x)\phi^{\prime}(x)dx, \,\, \forall \,\, \phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}) $$
I am not sure how to proceed from here, many techniques that are used to manipulate integrals require the integrand to be at least continuous. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: Put the $f_0$ on the other side, then you just need to find $f_1$ such that $f_1' = \delta_0 - f_0$ and $f_1$ is in $L^2$. But the solution of $f' = \delta_0$ is $f= H + C$ where $H$ is the Heaviside function. Art the end, you will need to have a condition on $f_0$ to ensure that $f_1$ converges to $0$ when $x\to\pm\infty$

Comment: Hint: Let $f_1(x)=\frac{1}{2}{\rm sgn}(x) e^{-x^2}$.